# How to get index of row in ant design table?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ant-design-pro

I want to show index of rows in ant design table. eg: 1 to 10 for 10 rows data i got.

```
const columns = [{
    title: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    width: '5%'
  },
...
];
<Table key="table" columns={columns} dataSource={listData} pagination= {false} />
```

fixed:

```
title: "ID", width: "5%", render: (text, record) => ( listData.indexOf(record) + 1 ) i fixed it
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    const columns = [{
    title: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    width: '5%',
    **render:(item, record, index)=>(<>{index}</>)**
  }]
    <Table key="table" columns={columns} dataSource={listData} pagination= {false}/>
```

you can find the index from your dataset by rendering the column.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `render` for sorting EX:

```js
    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'SL ID',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            key: 'id',
            sorter: (a, b) => a.id - b.id,
            render: (id, record, index) => { ++index; return index; },
            showSorterTooltip: false,
            
            
        },
        {
            title: 'Company Type',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            key: 'name',
        },
        {
            title: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            key: 'description',
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear. Better you show us the output you want to achieve. If you need to get index of the objects in your 'columns' array then you can use iterators to get that.

Eg - 1:

```
columns.map((column, index) => {
  // Your statements will go here
})
```

Eg - 2:

```
columns.forEach((column, index) => {
  // Your statements will go here
})
```

Realtime example:

```
<Table key="table" columns={columns} dataSource={listData} pagination= {false} >
  <tbody>
      {columns.map((column, index) => (
        <row>
          <td>{index}</td>
        </row>
      ))}
    }
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

There are other iterators too like 'lodash' 'forEach'. This could be your start learning iterators https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp

Comment: I mean like https://blog.sqlauthority.com/i/b/noindex1.jpg, first column in this image. I dont know what does this mean in english?

Comment: Can you provide 'listData' details?

Comment: Just type json i get from server, and i want to show index instead of ID for security

Comment: title: "ID",
      width: "5%",
      render: (text, record) => (
      listData.indexOf(record) + 1
      ) i fixed it

Comment: @thaovd1712 thanks! using indexOf is a neat solution

Answer (score -1):

If you want the row indexes to display sequentially across different pages of the Ant Design Table component, you'll need to calculate the correct index based on the current page size and page number. You can achieve this by combining the `pagination` and `render` properties of the columns.

Here's an example of how you can display sequential row indexes across different pages:

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

const dataSource = [
  // Your data source array here
];

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Index',
    key: 'index',
    render: (text, record, index) => (currentPage - 1) * pageSize + index + 1,
  },
  {
    title: 'Column 1',
    dataIndex: 'column1',
    key: 'column1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Column 2',
    dataIndex: 'column2',
    key: 'column2',
  },
  // ... other columns
];

const pageSize = 10; // Number of rows per page
let currentPage = 1; // Initialize with the current page number

const MyTable = () => {
  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
      pagination={{
        onChange: (page) => {
          currentPage = page; // Update the current page number
        },
      }}
      rowKey={(record, index) => index}
    />
  );
};

export default MyTable;
```

In this example, the `render` function calculates the sequential index based on the current page number (`currentPage`) and page size (`pageSize`), ensuring that the indexes are consistent across different pages. The `onChange` event of the `pagination` component updates the `currentPage` variable when the user switches to a different page.

Again, replace `'Column 1'`, `'Column 2'`, and other column titles, as well as the data source array, with your actual data and column configurations.